# Which programming language to choose?

Tags: c++, python, ruby-on-rails

I am a 3rd year CS engineering student, I have done some basic programming in languages like C,C++,Java,Shell,Perl,PHP,Ruby on Rails, Python. But now I wanted to settle for one language, so I thought of finally mastering one scripting language and other compiled one. So I decided to stick with C++ and Python. Can someone suggest me, would these be sufficient for any kind of programming, or for web designing I should stick to ROR?

Comment: "But now I wanted to settle for one language" => why ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness

Comment: They will be sufficient for any kind of programming. There are several excellent web frameworks for Python.

Comment: You should look into BCPL. I foresee a growing number of people becoming very interested in that language for its simplicity and power. Many say it's what C _should_ have been instead of the bloated monstrosity that came out of AT&T.

Comment: i think ever language has it own advantages, it ever depends on what you want/have to do

Comment: @Scorpi0: It's more useful to be very good at a few languages than not very good at many languages. I completely agree to focus on the languages you like best until you feel you have mastered them. That way you'll be able to produce good code faster.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed as off-topic exactly. It should've been closed because the question belongs on programmers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Omnifarious - I forgot about that. I'm an olde-timer whk still expects to see separate close options for "belongs on Meta" and such.

Comment: @omnifarious: "Belongs on ..." is a type of off-topic.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro - This is true, but it's not what people here used, since there is no link to programmers on the blurb.

Comment: @Omnifarious: OK, well, that's what I used anyway. Doesn't matter, it's likely to get moved by a moderator.

Comment: It really depends on what you are using the language for.  If you are programming video games, Python is the way to go.  If you're making online programs, use JavaScript.  Can you include how you are going to use your code?

Answer (score 4):

Go with what you feel most comfortable. But don't "settle" for one language. Programming languages are tools and you should be able to apply the right tool for the right problem.

For web dev in python:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebProgramming

Answer (score 0):

Presently ROR is high in demand for web. As a professional i'll suggest to learn ROR.

Answer (score 0):

Language should be a means to an end.  Pick a project you want to work on, then figure out what you will need to know to get the job done.  It's very difficult to get any language-learning to stick without some practical application.

And "knowing a language" is not particularly difficult or useful.  Knowing how to use most of the important libraries and platforms associated with a language is usually much more time-intensive and useful.

As far as picking a project if you can't think of one, maybe try for something on a mobile platform -- Android / iOS / Windows Phone.  These are generally useful for learning not only a language, but a complete set of tools to take an idea from concept to published.